# How to handle variables that need access to the rendered output of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in plain JS and HTML

```html
<div id="sketchWrapper">
    <div id="initiatorContainer"></div>
</div>
```

```js
const sketchWrapper = document.getElementById("sketchWrapper");
const sketch = initSketchWrapper(sketchWrapper).sketch;

const session = IK.initSession(APP_ID);
session.on("drawingCreated", (event) => {
    session.insert(event.drawing, "sketchWrapper");
    sketch();
}).connect(() => {
    session.initiate("initiatorContainer");
    sketch();
});
```

This code works and I want to use it in my React project. Since I need access to the HTML elements my first thought was to use `useEffect` because it's executed after the component was rendered.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const sketchEl = useRef();
  const initiatorEl = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const sketch = initSketchWrapper(sketchEl.current).sketch;
    const session = IK.initSession(APP_ID);

    session
      .on("drawingCreated", (event) => {
        session.insert(event.drawing, sketchEl.current);
        sketch();
      })
      .connect(() => {
        session.initiate(initiatorEl.current);
        sketch();
      });
  });

  return (
    <div ref={sketchEl}>
      <div ref={initiatorEl} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code works but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. And if I want to extend the component to add a function that needs access to the defined `sketch` constant how could this be done? Because currently the `sketch` constant is only accessible inside the `useEffect` but I can't define it outside of it because it needs access to the rendered output of the component.

```js
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    // ... some code
    sketch()  // <- can't access this because it's inside the useEffect function
}
```

Comment: You can set  `const [sketch, setSketch] = useState()`. Then use setSketch in useEffect

Comment: Pass an empty array as second argument to useEffect and store sketch in a ref: `const sketchRef = useRef(); ` and in the effect: `sketchRef.current = sketch`

Comment: @KostyaTresko @HMR thanks for the suggestions. I've also thought about using `useState` but I wasn't sure if state should be used for something like this. The `useRef` approach also sound promising. Is there an advantage or disadvantage in using one of these solutions? I'm not sure which one is better in my use case.

Comment: I also think that the solution of @HMR is the best approach

Comment: @SafiNettah Is there a specific reason why you prefer this approach? Because from the React docs it seems refs should be only used if you need to access DOM nodes.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake. I've read about refs in class components but in function components `useRef` is a good way to "imitate" instance variables; Reference: [Is there something like instance variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)